# Angular-gridster: on drop listerner

Tags: angularjs, drag-and-drop, draggable, drag, gridster

Is there a way to find out whenever an item has been dropped? I found a snippet in their documentation, but i don't know if this is what I'm looking for. I tried using it but then I don't have any luck.

The code:

```
scope.$on('gridster-item-transition-end', function(item) {
 // item.$element
 // item.gridster
 // item.row
 // item.col
 // item.sizeX
 // item.sizeY
 // item.minSizeX
 // item.minSizeY
 // item.maxSizeX
 // item.maxSizeY
})
```

Comment: have you tried giving your own function to `$scope.gridsterOpts.draggable.drag` , start or stop ?

Comment: I didn't. actually I don't know how to do it..

Comment: What angular gridster are you using ? I found 2 different repo's about it

Comment: this one https://github.com/ManifestWebDesign/angular-gridster

Comment: Here : https://github.com/ManifestWebDesign/angular-gridster#configuration 

The last part of the object should be what you're looking for

Comment: ohhh. I did that already. I've already set my configuration. My problem now is to detect whenever an item has been dropped.

Comment: makes sense! can you give an answer, so that I can give you an upvote or mark it as the answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111808/discussion-between-chitcharonko-and-andrew-donovan).